# How do I get to ModPE to perform a function the first time a mod is opened?

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, modding

I am making a Minecraft PE mod and I want to set a variable *only* on the first launch of the mod. So, how do I make it it set the variable and then not set it again until I import the mod again?

Answer (score 1):

```
function newLevel() {
   if (ModPE.readData("firstLaunch") != true) {
         ModPe.saveData("firstLaunch", true);
         clientMessage("This is the first launch");
   } else {
         clientMessage("This is not the first launch");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway use newLevel template

```
function newLevel()
{
    //Content
}
```

This will get called at the start of a new level and only at the start

If you want even more flexibility then use rhino and run on the games ui thread. With ModPE you are limited to using the pre made templates and newLevel is your best bet unless you know rhino then you have more flexibility as you can use Java and android libraries at your disposal.